# use different Locale in kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin

l want to add language to my app use string , lang English and Arabic . my app is flight schedule for specific airport via data json. and my app working fine with out problem . l want change the language are come from data json to Arabic language

String res in en

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="schedule">schedule</string>
    <string name="arrival">arrival</string>
    <string name="departed">departed</string>
    <string name="cancelled">cancelled</string>
</resources>
```

String res in arabic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="schedule">مجدولة</string>
    <string name="arrival">وصلت</string>
    <string name="departed">غادرت</string>
    <string name="cancelled">الغيت</string>

</resources>
```

l want use those resources in my list adapte because i used list view in my app

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false)

        val code = view.findViewById(R.id.code_id) as AppCompatTextView
        val status = view.findViewById(R.id.status_id) as AppCompatTextView
        val TimeFlight = view.findViewById(R.id.time_id) as AppCompatTextView
        val LogoAriline = view.findViewById(R.id.logo_image) as ImageView

        CallsingID.text = list[position].Callsign
        AirlineID.text = list[position].Airline
        code.text = list[position].code
        status.text= list[position].status
        TimeFlight.text = getDateTime(list[position].TimeFlight)
        Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse("https://www.xxxxxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/"+status.text.toString()+"_logo0.png"))
            .into(LogoAriline)



        return view as View
    }
```

l want add language inside of `status.text= list[position].status`

[image: my app]

Answer (score 0):

Add this flag in manifest under Application Tag.

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Locale Manage Utility Class

```
object LocaleManagerMew {

val SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "MEW_CURRENT_USER_LANGUAGE"
var mSharedPreference: SharedPreferences? = null

var mEnglishFlag = "en"
var mArabicFlag = "ar"

fun setLocale(context: Context?): Context {
    return updateResources(context!!, getCurrentLanguage(context)!!)
}

inline fun setNewLocale(context: Context, language: String) {

    persistLanguagePreference(context, language)
    updateResources(context, language)
}

inline fun getCurrentLanguage(context: Context?): String? {

    var mCurrentLanguage: String?

    if (mSharedPreference == null)
        mSharedPreference = PreferenceHelper.defaultPrefs(context!!)

    mCurrentLanguage = mSharedPreference!![SELECTED_LANGUAGE]

    return mCurrentLanguage
}

fun persistLanguagePreference(context: Context, language: String) {
    if (mSharedPreference == null)
        mSharedPreference = PreferenceHelper.defaultPrefs(context)

    mSharedPreference!![SELECTED_LANGUAGE] = language

}

fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String): Context {

    var contextFun = context

    var locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)

    var resources = context.resources
    var configuration = Configuration(resources.configuration)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
        contextFun = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    } else {
        configuration.locale = locale
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics())
    }
    return contextFun
}
}
```

Application Class Code

```
 override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        LocaleManagerMew.setLocale(this)
        Log.d(MewConstants.mewLogs, "onConfigurationChanged: " + newConfig.locale.getLanguage())
    }
```

Base Activity

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManagerMew.setLocale(base))
}
}
```

Language Change Button Click Listener in Activity

```
override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    when (p0?.id) {

        R.id.switchLanguage -> {
            //LocaleManagerMew.setLocale(this@LoginCustomerFragment.activity?.applicationContext)
            var mCurrentLanguage = LocaleManagerMew.getCurrentLanguage(this@LoginCustomerFragment.activity?.applicationContext)
            if (mCurrentLanguage == LocaleManagerMew.mArabicFlag) {
                LocaleManagerMew.setNewLocale(this@LoginCustomerFragment.context!!, LocaleManagerMew.mEnglishFlag)
            } else if (mCurrentLanguage == LocaleManagerMew.mEnglishFlag) {
                LocaleManagerMew.setNewLocale(this@LoginCustomerFragment.context!!, LocaleManagerMew.mArabicFlag)
            }
            activity?.recreate()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: l just want covert the language come from data json url for flight schedule so l used this code but the language still same `status.text= list[position].Stauts+R.array.planets_array`

Comment: You cant change data that you get from a response, you have to sort it with the person who made JSON API for you, to return Arabic and eng translation in the response and you choose to display the one you want according to the app localization, however, if the string names you are getting are static 100% you can work around it to see if the string name in API equal the word you have saved in your app then you can display the Arabic word. but I don't recommend doing it this way.

Comment: can l use if expression ?

Comment: what do you mean by that, also if you link us your response we can help you better

Comment: l mean use `if (schedule=="مجدولة")`

Comment: Yes you can do that but it's not the best way to do it, because if that word change in the backend you won't be able to display the right translation

Comment: can you please give me example how to do it ? l am new in kotlin .

Comment: You can do String1 = "AbBaCca";
String2 = "bac";  and  by using in operator String2 in String1
, Or if ("AbBaCca".contains("bac", ignoreCase = true)){//do logic}, if you need more help we can discuss it in chat instead

Comment: l used this code but dose not  change the mean of word `if (code.equals("scheduled")) {
            R.string.scheduled
        }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183420/discussion-between-hossam-scott-and-pabloescobar).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the line of:

```
code.text = context.getString(
        when (list[position].code) {
            "schedule" -> R.string.schedule
            "arrival" -> R.string.arrival
            "departed" -> R.string.departed
            "cancelled" -> R.string.cancelled
            else -> TODO("This is an error")
        }
    )
```